# Gatsby Failed Deployment to Netlify: Failed to validate error { ValidationError: child "error" fails because ["error" must be an object]

Tags: gatsby, netlify

I am trying to deploy a Gatsby site (backend is Contenful) but get the following error from Netlify deployment logs. I can't make sense of the error hence unable to pinpoint where the error is coming from?

The issue occurs only during deployment. The site is working fine in development. I have checked my env variables on Netlify and they are set correctly.

Anyone came across such a cryptic error message before and has managed to resolve it? Appreciate any pointers. Thanks

```
6:22:50 AM: Failed to validate error { ValidationError: child "error" fails because ["error" must be an object]
6:22:50 AM:     at Object.exports.process (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/@hapi/joi/lib/errors.js:202:19)
6:22:50 AM:     at internals.Object._validateWithOptions (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/@hapi/joi/lib/types/any/index.js:764:31)
6:22:50 AM:     at module.exports.internals.Any.root.validate (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/@hapi/joi/lib/index.js:145:23)
6:22:50 AM:     at constructError (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/structured-errors/construct-error.js:28:29)
6:22:50 AM:     at Object.error (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/reporter/index.js:100:29)
6:22:50 AM:     at Object.panic (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/reporter/index.js:58:24)
6:22:50 AM:     at reportFailure (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby/dist/commands/build.js:47:10)
6:22:50 AM:     at buildProductionBundle.catch.err (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby/dist/commands/build.js:102:5)
6:22:50 AM:   isJoi: true,
6:22:50 AM:   name: 'ValidationError',
6:22:50 AM:   details:
6:22:50 AM:    [ { message: '"error" must be an object',
6:22:50 AM:        path: [Array],
6:22:50 AM:        type: 'object.base',
6:22:50 AM:        context: [Object] } ],
6:22:50 AM:   _object:
6:22:50 AM:    { error:
6:22:50 AM:       [ './src/pages/about.js\nModule not found: Error: Can\'t resolve \'../components/Head\' in \'/opt/build/repo/src/pages\'\nresolve \'../components/Head\' in \'/opt/build/repo/src/pages\'\n  using description file: /opt/build/repo/package.json (relative path: ./src/pages)\n    Field \'browser\' doesn\'t contain a valid alias configuration\n    using description file: /opt/build/repo/package.json (relative path: ./src/components/Head)\n      no extension\n        Field \'browser\' doesn\'t contain a valid alias configuration\n        /opt/build/repo/src/components/Head doesn\'t exist\n      .mjs\n        Field \'browser\' doesn\'t contain a valid alias configuration\n        /opt/build/repo/src/components/Head.mjs doesn\'t exist\n      .js\n        Field \'browser\' doesn\'t contain a valid alias configuration\n        /opt/build/repo/src/components/Head.js doesn\'t exist\n      .jsx\n        Field \'browser\' doesn\'t contain a valid alias configuration\n        /opt/build/repo/src/components/Head.jsx doesn\'t exist\n      .wasm\n        Field \'browser\' doesn\'t contain a valid alias configuration\n        /opt/build/repo/src/components/Head.wasm doesn\'t exist\n      .json\n        Field \'browser\' doesn\'t contain a valid alias configuration\n        /opt/build/repo/src/components/Head.json doesn\'t exist\n      as directory\n        /opt/build/repo/src/components/Head doesn\'t exist\n[/opt/build/repo/src/components/Head]\n[/opt/build/repo/src/components/Head.mjs]\n[/opt/build/repo/src/components/Head.js]\n[/opt/build/repo/src/components/Head.jsx]\n[/opt/build/repo/src/components/Head.wasm]\n[/opt/build/repo/src/components/Head.json]\n @ ./src/pages/about.js 3:0-38 6:63-67\n @ ./.cache/async-requires.js\n @ ./.cache/production-app.js',
6:22:50 AM:         './src/pages/404.js\nModule not found: Error: Can\'t resolve \'../components/Head\' in \'/opt/build/repo/src/pages\'\nresolve \'../components/Head\' in \'/opt/build/repo/src/pages\'\n  using description file: /opt/build/repo/package.json (relative path: ./src/pages)\n    Field \'browser\' doesn\'t contain a valid alias configuration\n    using description file: /opt/build/repo/package.json (relative path: ./src/components/Head)\n      no extension\n        Field \'browser\' doesn\'t contain a valid alias configuration\n        /opt/build/repo/src/components/Head doesn\'t exist\n      .mjs\n        Field \'browser\' doesn\'t contain a valid alias configuration\n        /opt/build/repo/src/components/Head.mjs doesn\'t exist\n      .js\n        Field \'browser\' doesn\'t contain a valid alias configuration\n        /opt/build/repo/src/components/Head.js doesn\'t exist\n      .jsx\n        Field \'browser\' doesn\'t contain a valid alias configuration\n        /opt/build/repo/src/components/Head.jsx doesn\'t exist\n      .wasm\n        Field \'browser\' doesn\'t contain a valid alias configuration\n        /opt/build/repo/src/components/Head.wasm doesn\'t exist\n      .json\n        Field \'browser\' doesn\'t contain a valid alias configuration\n        /opt/build/repo/src/components/Head.json doesn\'t exist\n      as directory\n        /opt/build/repo/src/components/Head doesn\'t exist\n[/opt/build/repo/src/components/Head]\n[/opt/build/repo/src/components/Head.mjs]\n[/opt/build/repo/src/components/Head.js]\n[/opt/build/repo/src/components/Head.jsx]\n[/opt/build/repo/src/components/Head.wasm]\n[/opt/build/repo/src/components/Head.json]\n @ ./src/pages/404.js 4:0-38 7:63-67\n @ ./.cache/async-requires.js\n @ ./.cache/production-app.js',
6:22:50 AM:         './src/pages/contact.js\nModule not found: Error: Can\'t resolve \'../components/Head\' in \'/opt/build/repo/src/pages\'\nresolve \'../components/Head\' in \'/opt/build/repo/src/pages\'\n  using description file: /opt/build/repo/package.json (relative path: ./src/pages)\n    Field \'browser\' doesn\'t contain a valid alias configuration\n    using description file: /opt/build/repo/package.json (relative path: ./src/components/Head)\n      no extension\n        Field \'browser\' doesn\'t contain a valid alias configuration\n        /opt/build/repo/src/components/Head doesn\'t exist\n      .mjs\n        Field \'browser\' doesn\'t contain a valid alias configuration\n        /opt/build/repo/src/components/Head.mjs doesn\'t exist\n      .js\n        Field \'browser\' doesn\'t contain a valid alias configuration\n        /opt/build/repo/src/components/Head.js doesn\'t exist\n      .jsx\n        Field \'browser\' doesn\'t contain a valid alias configuration\n        /opt/build/repo/src/components/Head.jsx doesn\'t exist\n      .wasm\n        Field \'browser\' doesn\'t contain a valid alias configuration\n        /opt/build/repo/src/components/Head.wasm doesn\'t exist\n      .json\n        Field \'browser\' doesn\'t contain a valid alias configuration\n        /opt/build/repo/src/components/Head.json doesn\'t exist\n      as directory\n        /opt/build/repo/src/components/Head doesn\'t exist\n[/opt/build/repo/src/components/Head]\n[/opt/build/repo/src/components/Head.mjs]\n[/opt/build/repo/src/components/Head.js]\n[/opt/build/repo/src/components/Head.jsx]\n[/opt/build/repo/src/components/Head.wasm]\n[/opt/build/repo/src/components/Head.json]\n @ ./src/pages/contact.js 3:0-38 6:63-67\n @ ./.cache/async-requires.js\n @ ./.cache/production-app.js',
6:22:50 AM:         './src/pages/index.js\nModule not found: Error: Can\'t resolve \'../components/Head\' in \'/opt/build/repo/src/pages\'\nresolve \'../components/Head\' in \'/opt/build/repo/src/pages\'\n  using description file: /opt/build/repo/package.json (relative path: ./src/pages)\n    Field \'browser\' doesn\'t contain a valid alias configuration\n    using description file: /opt/build/repo/package.json (relative path: ./src/components/Head)\n      no extension\n        Field \'browser\' doesn\'t contain a valid alias configuration\n
```

Answer (score 1):

The crux of the error lies here

Error: Can\'t resolve \'../components/Head\

because netlify filesystem is case sensitive, i should have imported as ../components/head instead of ../components/Head

once that has been resolved, the deployment works!

Comment: Thank you! I had 2 capitalization typos that weren't breaking locally but broke the deploy.